# Pick Save Path from a Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Const SAVE_PATH = "S:\Divisional Support\RVU Programs\Payroll 2015\2015-04 April\PDF's\Baptist Easley"

'paste file destination in the above location'

   Dim cell As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim counter As Long

   Set wsSummary = Sheets("PERFORM. SUM. - EASLEY")

   For Each cell In Worksheets("NAME KEY").Range("$H:$H")
      If cell.Value <> "" Then

         'progress in status bar
         counter = counter + 1
         Application.StatusBar = "Processing file: " & counter & "/1042"

         With wsSummary
            .Range("$A$4").Value = cell.Value
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                  Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                  Filename:=SAVE_PATH & "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf", _
                  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                  IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                  OpenAfterPublish:=False
         End With
      End If
  Next cell


   Set wsSummary = Nothing
End Sub
```

My issue is simple instead of having to step into the code to change the location where it's saved: `Const SAVE_PATH = "S:\Divisional Support\RVU Programs\Payroll 2015\2015-04 April\PDF's\Baptist Easley"`

I want to be able to post that location in cell `J2`, how will I code that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to be able to post that location in cell J2, how will I code that?

It's very simple actually

Replace the line

```
FileName:=SAVE_PATH & "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf"
```

with

```
FileName:=Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").Value & _
          "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf"
```

Change the `Thisworkbook` and `Sheet1` to the relevant workbook or sheet.

Comment: Won't that just change the name it's save with?  I want to point the macro to the location I want the pdf saved.

Comment: I am assuming that the cell `J2` has `"S:\Divisional Support\RVU Programs\Payroll 2015\2015-04 April\PDF's\Baptist Easley"`

Comment: Assuming cell `J2` contains the complete path to where you want to save the file, this will do exactly what you asked. Of course, the danger is that `cell.value` refers to the _currently active_ cell, so there's no telling what the file name will be.

Comment: What about const Save path reference?  That doesn't have any effect?

Comment: You can safely delete it from the top of your code @user3666237. You now don't need it :)